# Atomic integer increment

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, increment

Lets have a function that increments an global atomic integer and then we store that value in a non-atomic local variable

```
_Atomic int atom = 0 ;

void function( void )
{   
    int a = atom++ ;
}
```

Will `a` always have unique value when using the above code with multiple threads. If it will, as some commenters have suggested, then what is the point of functions like [`atomic_fetch_add`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_add).

Comment: What makes you think that access to `atomic_global_integer` is actually atomic? If it was, `a` wouldn't receive the same value in two threads.

Comment: @interjay It is atomic. Defined as `_Atomic int;` for example. `a` definitely can receive the same value in the first case.

Comment: In that case either your implementation is buggy or you're changing `atomic_global_integer` elsewhere.

Comment: @interjay Yes in another thread. Read the full question please.

Comment: I read the full question.... I meant you're changing it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @interjay No, only in that function.

Comment: I stand by my comment about a bug in code you haven't shown, or in the implementation. Post a [complete example](http://sscce.org/) if you believe otherwise.

Comment: @self.: interjay’s point is that you are changing `atomic_global_integer` somewhere other than in that one `atomic_global_integer++` expression. You say “only in that function”, but that does not exclude another piece of code in the same function. The alternative is that your C implementation has a bug or `atomic_global_integer` has been declared incorrectly (not as `atomic`) or some preprocessor issue is changing the code (e.g., some `#define` changes `atomic_global_integer` to be something else), or that the behavior you suggest was not actually observed.

Comment: @interjay Well that is my problem. So in between the assigning the value to `a`, another increment cannot happen? Let me edit for clarity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is the only line with the increment to that variable in the code.

Comment: Another increment can happen at any point but the values of `a` will still be unique.

Comment: @self.: Show the code, including the definition and the initialization of `atomic_global_integer`. Also, how did you conclude that different threads can get the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the "_Atomic" keyword.  Is this new C++11 thing?  In any case, you should use atomic intrinsics built into most platforms and cpu architectures.  (ala "lock add" in x86).

On GCC/Clang, the function would want to call is [__sync_add_and_fetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html). On Windows, it's called [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And on some gcc architectures that are still targeting i386, you have to manually do this in assembly. (Although this won't work on a real 80386, lock intrinsics didn't get introduced until 80486, but I digress...)

```
unsigned int xadd_4(volatile void* pVal, unsigned int inc)
{
    unsigned int result;
    unsigned int* pValInt = (unsigned int*)pVal;

    asm volatile( 
        "lock; xaddl %%eax, %2;"
        :"=a" (result) 
        : "a" (inc), "m" (*pValInt) 
        :"memory" );

    return (result);
}

int AtomicIncrement(int* pInt)
{
    COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sizeof(int)==4);   
    // InterlockedIncrement
    unsigned int result = xadd_4(pInt, 1) + 1;
    return (int)result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the information I was looking for. ( SO can be pretty useless regarding actual information sometimes.)

Comment: I'm assuming mutex would also work.( and even with non-atomic )?

Comment: _Atomic is the new keyword in C11 supported by almost nothing.

Comment: Mutex also works. And is safer for programmers less experienced with threads and atomics (and probably safer for experienced programmers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use assembly insert, with CompareAndSwap operations (cas).
For intel/gcc, following sample works (with using cmpxchg):

```
static inline uint32_t u32cas(volatile uint32_t *ptr, uint32_t old_val, uint32_t new_val) {
   uint32_t prev_val;
   __asm__ __volatile__("lock; cmpxchgl %k1,%2"
                        : "=a"(prev_val)
                        : "q"(new_val), "m"(*(volatile uint32_t *)(ptr)), "0"(old_val)
                        : "memory");
   return prev_val;
}


uint32_t atom = 0;


void atomic_increment() {
  uint32_t x;
  do {
    x = atom;
  } while(u32cas(&atom, x, x + 1) != x);
}
```

Also, on FreeBSD, you can use

> man atomic